# How to model an algorithm to apply discounts to prices?

Tags: algorithm, e-commerce

I was asked to developed a solution to apply easily applying discounts to products in a ecommerce store and I tried to do it in the most generic way.

Let's say we have the following products:

- Product A: $5
- Product B: $20
- Product C: $7.50

And we have the following discounts:

- 2-for-1 for the Product A
- If you buy 3 or more items of the Product B, the price per unit should be 19.00€.

To do so, I modeled a class called Pricing Rule that contains the following data:

- **min_items**: min number of purchased items necessary to apply the discount.
- **discounted_items_rate**: percentage of products affected by the discount.
- **price_reduction**: percentage of price reduction applicable to the items with discount.

Using this class, the 2-for-1 discount would be

- min_items: 2. At least there should be 2 items in the cart.
- discounted_items_rate: 0.5. Half of the items will get a discount
- price_reduction: 1. That means, the price reduction will be 100%.

And in a similar way, the 3 or more items of the product B for $19 would be:

- min_items: 3
- discounted_items_rate: 1 (all of them)
- price_reduction: 0.05 ($19 instead of 20$ is a price reduction of the 5%).

I modeled a formula to determine the total price, the formula would be:

(Forget about the correctness of the code, imagine we iterate correctly over the CART and we select the appropriate PRICING_RULE. Imagine the cart like CART = { productA: 10 items, productB: 6 items, .... })

```
if (CART.PRODUCT.ITEMS > PRICING_RULE.min_items) [It has a discount]
    var items_with_discount = floor(CART.PRODUCT.ITEMS * PRICING_RULE.discounted_items_rate)
    var with_discount = items_with_discount * price * (1 -PRICING_RULE.price_reduction)
    var without_discount = (CART.PRODUCT.ITEMS - items_with_discount) * price
    total += (with_discount + without_discount)
else [It does not have a discount]
    total += CART.PRODUCT.ITEMS * price
```

For example if I buy 5 items of the product A, the total price would be 5 * 5 = $25, but I have a 2-for-1 discount, so the price would be $15.

Following the algorithm:

```
items_with_discount = floor(5 * 0.5) = floor(2.5) = 2
with_discount = 2 * 5 * (1 - 1) = 0
without_discount = (5 - 2) * 5 = 15
total += 0 + 15 = $15
```

It works for lots of popular discounts (5-for-3, 3-for-1, 8% discount for all products, 3 or more for X-price, .... any typical discount).

I got the feedback that it seems complex, but I actually find it very simple.
What is the best way to model an algorithm to **apply discounts in a generic way**?

Comment: I don't see a clear problem statement.  At various points, you state that the target problem is "a generic way", a specific list of discount classes, and "any typical discount".  First of all, the listed discounts are *not* compatible types, to be folded into some general solution.  Second, "any typical" merely pushes the problem statement from the customer (the store) to the programmer -- exactly the wrong direction.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you take a hint from Agile methodology, and broaden the discussion with the customer.  The original problem has large undefined areas: what discounts to handle, and what algorithm(s) to use.  Keep asking "Why?" on the algorithm side, to find out what aspects of the code are important to the customer.  At the moment, the problem appears to be demonstrably unsolvable: give me succinct, generic code to handle unspecified special cases.  Information theory can disprove *that* one in about three lines.

Comment: For instance, a common discount in my area is something like "3 for $10, maximum purchase of 12; otherwise $4 each.  By the way, the regular price of a case (30) is $96.  The 3 for $10 deal is good only Tuesdays, while supplies last."  Even worse, compare some holiday sales when there's a combo deal, such as charcoal (regularly $8/bag, on sale for $7) and grilling tongs ($4) sell together for $10, this weekend only, and you also get a coupon good for $2 off anything at the butcher counter *next* weekend.  Purchase limits apply.